# Appending hr tag to a div element in html using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list that is get populated when the user use the search box.
this is the overall structure:

```
<div id="searchResult">
<div>
<a href="#">result1</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#">result2</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#">result3</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to add a separator `<hr/>` between the child div elements,
I made the same thing when I added an image next to each result term using javascript:

```
 <script>
        function appendArrows() {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('searchResult');
            var list = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');

            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {

                var _img = document.createElement('img');
                _img.src = "Images/navigation Icon.png";
                _img.id = "arr";
                list[i].appendChild(_img);
</script>
```

But since there is no just append function in JavaScript, I 'm stuck in this separator.

Comment: `appendChild()` is the append method used in JavaScript.

Comment: Or you could just set a bottom border on the div and use padding/margins

Answer (score 1):

I like @epascarello suggestion better, but if you want to use JavaScript, then just add the following line to your existing code:

```
    function appendArrows() {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('searchResult');
        var list = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');

        for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {

            var _img = document.createElement('img');
            _img.src = "Images/navigation Icon.png";
            _img.id = "arr";
            list[i].appendChild(_img);
            var hzRule = document.createElement('hr');// make a hr
            list[i].appendChild(hzRule);// append the hr

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the child divs and then add `hr` tag to its html.

1) Get all the child divs like

`var childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#searchResult div');`

2) Do a loop and add the `hr` tag to each div.

`for(var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++){
  childDivs[i].outerHTML += "<hr/>;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the JQuery library, more specifically its `append()` function:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $( "#searchResult" ).append( "<hr />" );
});
```

I used `a` as the selector in the example but you can feel free to change it. By clicking the link (or `a`) it will append the `<hr />` into the search result ID.

To read more about the `append()` function (or the library in general) look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).